# Can I shorten the word "subtitles" to "sub's"?

Tags: abbreviations

I wanted to use the form of colloquial speech in my writing, having the word abbreviation in context to simplify speech.

"It's cool that you to create english sub's"

and

"It's cool that you to create english subtitles"

In this form, the meaning of the word has not changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When speaking with a group of people who share a common interest you may encounter abbreviations such as the one you suggest. In which case using such terms can be be both efficient and also give a sense of belonging to group. However introducing a new abbreviation needs to be done with caution.

In this case, unless you've seen **subs** in use elsewhere in conversation about subtitling I would not expect it to be immediately understood. As it happens in other context subs is an abbreviation of submarines, and also in football/soccer for substitutes.

Comment: You have provided surely usefull info from me. Thank you for such detailed response.